# ARC : Is this approach correct

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

This may sound a newbie question however I'm new to iOS dev.

I've following code in my project, the project is ARC enabled, and I get error on its execution (bad access), and would like to understand the cause of the problem and solve it.

on some button press following code is invoked in `MTClassA.m` file

```
-(void) someMethod
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        ...
        (param1 and param2 are location variables)
        ... 
        mFlickr = [[MTFlickr alloc] initWithParam1:param1 param2:mparam2];
        mFlickr.delegate = self;
        [mFlickr fetchImages];
    }  
}
```

in `MTClassA.h` header file mFlickr is declared as `MTFlickr* mFlickr` so default it it with `__strong` qualifier.

the callback function of `fetchImages` class is following

```
- (void)didRecieveImageLinksFromFlickr:(NSArray*)response 
                                param1:(NSString*)param1 param2:(NSString*)param2 {
     ... 
}
```

So basically I would like to know is it correct to create mFlickr objects this way in for loop and expect the callback to work correctly, if no please suggest what need to be changed ?

P.S. Do I need to change mFlickr to local variable ? If yes how should I be guaranteed that param1 and param2 methods are the one's that I've passed for teach iteration in for loop ?

Comment: somehow you need to keep the multiple `MTFlickr ` objects alive (in an `NSMutableArray` maybe), because your loop keeps the very current object alive only, regarding you have only one assumable strong pointer which over this scope, that is the `mFlickr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating multiple instances of the mFlickr object within your loop, and presumably assigning them to the same instance variable. Under ARC an assignment to an instance variable will automatically release the previous value, so your mFlickr objects are getting destroyed as soon as they are created (except the last one).

Presumably your mFlickr object is setting itself as a delegate for a URL request, it is probably this callback which is failing since the request's delegate no longer exists.

If you are creating multiple instances you should store them in an array instance variable. The callback should include a reference to the particular instance that has returned, and at *this* point, you remove it from the array.

Comment: Wow thanks for detailed answer. To tell the truth I also though of keeping in array, but I feel it is not so nice solution... Does it make sense to achieve this by using __autoreleasing to mFlickr object or to make ARC to not remove the previous mFlickr object but release it in callback (kind of make object as "memory leak"... hope you get my idea) ...

Comment: To be honest I think an array is a nicer solution than trying to force ARC to do anything. You can't manually release objects under ARC so your second idea won't work. Something somewhere needs a strong pointer to each mFlickr object, you have a variable number of them, an array seems sensible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the mFLicker to local variable. The only thing that i found in your code wrong is that, you are immediately setting mFlicker to self after initializing it. i think you must want to set the delegate of the mFlicker that you can do it by

```
[mFlicker setDelegate:self]
```

Comment: Yes sorry fixed in original post

Comment: But in this case is it correct to get the callout working correctly at all ? I mean the callout parameters 'param1' and 'param2' might be changed when allocing and initing mFlickr in for loop. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set @property for mFlicker?

```
.h
@property(nonatomic, retain) MTFlickr *mflicker;

.m
@synthesis mflicker;
```

I also had similar experience, ARC was releasing my object after initialization.
so try changing your code to

```
self.mFlickr = [[MTFlickr alloc] initWithParam1:param1 param2:mparam2];
mFlickr.delegate = self;
[mFlickr fetchImages];
```

I am also not sure but i just wanted to provide some help

Comment: Basically I would like to get solution using ARC not MRC, can suggest something in ARC ?

Comment: You can't use retain in ARC mode also in header file. And one more thing why do I need to declare property in the same MTClassA class ? I'm using mFlickr on in it...